# How can I pass a unique code to my mobile app through a URL in the download link?

Tags: android, iphone

I need to present links to a user in an email body to download a native mobile app that I'm developing (there will be one link for IOS and anther for Android). I'd like the link to take them to the respective app store to download the app.

The user would then download and open the app.

When they open the app, The user need to put a unique code into the app to authorize the user.

Instead of showing the user the unique code in the email to enter into the mobile app, is there anyway I can put it in the URL of the download link to be passed to the app automatically after it's downloaded?

Ideally the user only needs to do one step, select a link to download the app and pass the link automatically.

Thank you!

I've researched on stackoverflow if there is a solution for this, but I haven't seen any capabilities out there.

Comment: You're looking for deep links. On Android more specifically you want to implement app links which are verified links that your app can open automatically when a link is clicked anywhere. This way you can also lass data directly into the app when it opens the link.

Comment: If you want this url to survive the round-trip to the app store, you might also consider _deferred_ deep links such as offered by [Branch.io](https://www.branch.io/glossary/deferred-deep-linking/) or Firebase [Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/).